# Send mail via Microsoft Graph as Application (Any User)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

We recently migrated from on premise exchange to Microsoft 365 and I'm wanting to turn on 2FA for all users (Enable security defaults). However this disables SMTP authentication which we have been using for sending mail from a distribution group address. (Not achievable via EWS as it doesn't have a physical mailbox)

From what I can see, the only method would be to set up a SMTP relay or send via Microsoft Graph.

I've tried going down the Microsoft Graph route, and here's what I've got so far.

1. Create application in Azure Active Directory > App Registrations
2. Add `Mail.Send` and `User.Read.All` (Application, not delegated) API Permissions and have granted Admin Consent.
3. Request token using the following

   - Generate auth code via [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{AzureApi.TenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={AzureApi.ClientId}&redirect_uri={WebUtility.UrlEncode(RedirectUrl)}&scope=offline_access%20Mail.Send%20User.Read.All](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BAzureApi.TenantId%7D/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=%7BAzureApi.ClientId%7D&redirect_uri=%7BWebUtility.UrlEncode(RedirectUrl)%7D&scope=offline_access%20Mail.Send%20User.Read.All) [using admin credentials]
   - Post request to [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{AzureApi.TenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BAzureApi.TenantId%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token) with the following request body.
     `{ "grant_type": "authorization_code", "client_id": "AzureApi.ClientId", "client_secret": "AzureApi.ClientSecret", "code": "insert auth code", "redirect_uri": "insert redirect URL" }` to get the bearer token
4. Once I have the token, Now I perform a request to send some mail

   - [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{fromAddress}/sendMail](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7BfromAddress%7D/sendMail)
   - This works when `fromAddress` is the email address of the user that requested the token, however when I try to send from a different address it gives this error `{"error":{"code":"ErrorAccessDenied","message":"Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."}}`
   - I even tried adding the `SendAs` permission to the token user for the mailbox I was trying to send as, but this didn't make any difference. Regardless - I want to be able to send as any user without delegating permissions to each mailbox.

Glad of any help. Thanks!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The behavior you are getting is expected because you are using delegated permissions - [authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow). This flow will not allow your app to send email as any user except the user that is signed in/"requested the token".

In your case you can add the permissions as application permissions and then use [Client Credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) with either secret or certificate(more secure). Your token request will look like the [Get Access Token Section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token). Note that this means two things:

- Your app will need to be secured on server side to protect the credentials.
- An admin will need to consent to the permissions on Azure AD
- Your app will be able to send emails as any user in your tenant so it is very sensitive.
- With application permissions you only need **Mail.Send**

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly it! Client Credentials flow worked

Comment: "Your app will be able to send emails as any user in your tenant so it is very sensitive." ಥ_ಥ

Comment: can't we send mail as any user(which has given permission to send on behalf) using the delegated permission??

Comment: This will open all kinds of security issues. Imagine any user can send emails as any user. Breaks context of user mailbox. This only works with delegated mailbox or share mailbox. Unless the user shares the mailbox so that the other user can manage on their behalf.

Comment: I had the same question about limiting access to some mailboxes and unattended auth. Here's the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76223165/5794437).

Answer (score 3):

I could test sending emails from an application (with any user) with postman.

First get a token:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant ID>/oauth2/v2.0/token?grant_type=client_credentials
Key     Value
client_id   <client ID>
scope       https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
client_secret   <secret>
grant_type  client_credentials

Response:
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "ext_expires_in": 3599,
    "access_token": <token>
}
```

Send email:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/c_jdoddi@innominds.com/sendMail
Authorization Bearer Token: <Bearer token>
Body
{ 
    "message" : { 
        "subject": "test email with any user", 
        "body" : { 
            "contentType": "html", 
            "content": "sending from postman" 
        }, 
        "toRecipients": [ 
            { 
                "emailAddress" : { 
                    "address" : <to email address>
                } 
            }
        ] ,
        "ccRecipients": [ 
            { 
                "emailAddress" : { 
                    "address" : <cc email address>
                } 
            }
        ] ,
        "bccRecipients": [ 
            { 
                "emailAddress" : { 
                    "address" : <bcc email address>
                } 
            }
        ] 
    } 
}

Response:
202 Accepted
```

Answer (score 0):

To restrict the App Registration to only be able to send as specific mailboxes, you need to add an Application Access Policy in Exchange Online.

Here's my steps to set up the App Registration to suit the application and limit its access to the specific mailbox(es):

Create an App Registration for your sending application.  Name it to suit.

Grant the App Registration permissions to send email using the method that suits the application.

a.   Click on "API permissions"

b.  Click on "+ Add a permission"

c.   Click on "APIs my organization uses"

d.   Search for "Office", then select "Office 365 Exchange Online"

e.   Click on "Application Permissions"

f. Find and add the permission for the method to be used to send email

```
EWS "full_access_as_app"

SMTP "SMTP.SendAsApp"

Graph "Mail.Send"
```

A Global Admin will need to grant consent once the permissions have been added.

Create a Mail-enabled Security Group with the mailboxes the application is to be permitted to send as members.

Create an Application Access Policy in Exchange Online to restrict the App Registration to the mailboxes in the Mail-enabled Security Group.

New-ApplicationAccessPolicy -AppId "" -PolicyScopeGroupId "Mail-enabled Security Group name" -AccessRight RestrictAccess

Create a secret key for App Registration

The application will need the TenantID, AppID and the Secret key to request an OAUTH token from Azure with the appropriate rights.